# Why is my html and app.js not linking While the css seems to be?

Tags: javascript

I cannot understand why my html (input box text, message displayed after button click) is binding with my app.js.  The first issue I had was {{message}} displayed which I fixed by changing the folder/file calls.  I am pretty sure they are correct and I now do not receive console errors.  But I still have no functionality.  Can anyone find a problem with the folder/file references, I am pretty sure my logic is correct.  If you discover something from a developer tool, please explain so that I can learn about diagnosing my own error.  There does not seem to be a problem with the styles reference, which is strange if I am calling files incorrectly. Thanks.  Here are 2 links:  [rendered, functionality not working](https://mccbjnn.github.io/AngularAssignment1/)

the code.][2](https://github.com/mccbjnn/AngularAssignment1)

Comment: You spellings are not correct please check `ng-controller="LunchCheckController"` and also your controller name

Comment: Thank you so much.  I spent a lot of time looking at semi colons and brackets!!!!